# Ubuntu 16.4 front panel audio not detected with ALC892

Tags: sound, panel, headphones

I have tried everything I could find on google to resolve the problem but nothing fixes it. The front and rear audio outputs appear in alsa but the front is always identified as unplugged. I am trying to use my headphones with the front panel audio and I cannot get the system to work.
If i connect my headphones to the rear panel, they appear as a line out and I get audio.
My motherboard is an EVGA SLI3 with the Realtek ALC982 chip on Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller

Is this a bug or is the device missing drivers for front panel audio?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo alsa force-reload` in a terminal. alsamixer It should be able to reconfigure everything from there. If that does not work then try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure alsamixer` and then `sudo alsa force-reload`.

Comment: force-reload did nothing. dpkg says alsamixer is not installed. apt-get says there is no package alsamixer. however, i can open alsamixer from the terminal by typing alsamixer. something is strange here.

Comment: Ah... I tried installing alsamixer as well and it said there was no package available. Seems the package is simply called "alsa." Do `sudo apt purge alsa` and then `sudo apt install alsa` once that is done. Once you reinstall set your audio inside the alsamixer daemon and then use the command `sudo alsactl store` it should be able to save your configuration.